# Designing a REST API: sub-collection and HTTP PATCH

Tags: rest, api-design

**First case:**

Let's say I have in my REST API a Customer resource available through the `/customers` and `/customers/{id}` endpoints.

Given that a customer can have multiple addresses, I have basically three options:

1. Add a `/customers/{id}/addresses` sub-collection endpoint. In that case, we can **GET**/**POST**/**PUT**/**DELETE** to that endpoint to get/add/modify/delete an address.
2. Add a `/addresses` endpoint representing top-level collection of addresses.
3. Do not create another endpoint, addresses are returned on **GET** `/customers/{id}` requests and can be added/modified/deleted with a **PATCH** request, eg. if we are using [JSON-PATCH](http://jsonpatch.com):

   ```
   PATCH /customers/{id}

   {
       "op": "add",
       "path": "/addresses/-",
       "value": /* new address */
   }
   ```

Which one would be the more appropriate in the case of a "general purpose" API (ie. a public API having multiple different clients with different needs)?

**Second case:**

Now let's consider a Document resource representing a document shared amongst multiple users, such as a Google Doc. Each time a user starts editing a document, its ID is added to the list of users currently editing that document, eg:

```
GET /documents/{id}

{
    "data": /* ... */,
    "editors": ["userId1", "userId2"]
}
```

Would you handle this the same way as the previous case?

The option #1 does not seem that natural to me because an editor in this case is just an ID (internally, a foreign key), can we consider an ID (and more generally a simple primitive type such as a string, integer, etc) as a resource?
Also, creating a different endpoint for each "sub-resource" will end up having lots of endpoints, whereas the **PATCH** option (#3) allows to keep a small number of endpoint while providing in addition the ability to update multiple sub-resources at the same time, eg:

```
PATCH /documents/{id}

[
    {"op": "add", "path": "/editors/-", "value": "idUser"},
    {"op": "replace", "path": "/title", "value "new title"}
]
```

Comment: I would choose the first one; I think it's the most normalized way. I don't like the second one because normally you will need a customer's addresses, not "just" addresses, so you would need a filter (query param, maybe) in each request. Not cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First option. If the `addresses` belongs to customer, that is, are not shared between different customer (at least, in the general case), I think the first option fits fine with a REST approach, since you model your system as a collection of resources and hierarchical relationship between them.

You could also use `PATCH` in combination with the first option in case you need to make partial updates of the addresses (for instance, if you only need to modify the name of the street)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed the first option seems quite natural regarding addresses. I added a second use case to my initial question, Is the first option still relevant here?

Comment: Yes, I would considerer editors as an attribute of each document and use the path /documents/{id}/editors to update it. IMHO, there is no difference from the first case. It does not matther if the editor is just an ID or a more complex structure.